# go template binding constant array values

Tags: arrays, go, go-templates

I am very new to go template; Can I know how I can bind an array with some constant values

I had tried below options; but not worked

```
{{ $groups := {"a", "b", "c"} }}
{{ $groups := ["a", "b", "c"] }}
{{ $groups := ("a", "b", "c") }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates do not support composite literal syntax for arrays or slices.

You can use a [custom template function](https://godoc.org/text/template#FuncMap) that returns its variadic arguments as a slice.

Here's the function:

```
func slice(v ...interface{}) []interface{} {
  return v
}
```

Add the function to the template's map before parsing:

```
 template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"slice": slice}).Parse(data)
```

Use it like this:

```
  {{$groups := slice "a" "b" "c"}}
```

<kbd>[working example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kOKfnlT42r)</kbd>